# Sort and transpose eigenvectors by eigenvalues in a nested ndarray in python

Tags: python, sorting, multidimensional-array

I believe this has not been answered yet for my specific problem.

Let's say I have an ndarray, that, only on the deepest two levels, contains actual square arrays that need to be diagonalized.

For simplicity, let's define the following

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig
a = np.array([[1,4,8],[2,9,3],[2,6,5]])
```

For this specific matrix, the eigensystem given by `eig(a)` is

```
eig(a)

EigResult(eigenvalues=array([13.54300945, -1.07781094,  2.53480149]), eigenvectors=array([[-0.554087  , -0.97321006,  0.82404034],
   [-0.61465955,  0.1385103 , -0.42744667],
   [-0.56141004,  0.18351316,  0.37181563]]))
```

As you can see, the eigenvalues 13.54,-1.07 and 2.53 are not sorted.

Let's now take an actual nested system of arrays I want diagonalized, as a test problem

```
b = np.array([[a,a,a,a],[a,a,a,a]])
e,v=eig(b)
```

Good news, `eig()` threads over arrays of arrays. But now I want two things: first, get the ordering on `e` and order eigenvalues in `e` and eigenvectors in `v` according to that ordering, and **transpose the eigenvectors** so that actually the very last axis on `v` spans the elements of each eigenvector (right now the second to last axis spans the elements, I think this is a common practice in linear algebra where eigenvectors are usually given as columns).

The first part, dealing with `e`, can be done by combining several solutions, namely `argsort` and `take_along_axis`

```
ordering=e.argsort(axis=-1)
e_sorted = np.take_along_axis(e, ordering, axis=-1)
```

How do I apply ordering to the eigenvectors `v`, so that they are ordered according to their eigenvalue, but at the same time, the last two axes are transposed? Whatever I try, the ordering just doesn't mesh with `v`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. First, some set up so we have a sufficiently robust example:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig

a = np.array([[345, 23, 2],
              [23, 4, 34],
              [2, 34, 5]])

b = np.array([[2, 2, 4],
              [2, 3, 5],
              [4, 5, 4]])

c = np.array([[a,b],[b,b]])

e,v=eig(c)
print(e[1,1])
print(v[1,1])
```

The output here is:

```
[10.6898736   0.43934625 -2.12921985]

[[-0.44860502 -0.77667543 -0.44218639]
 [-0.56625935  0.62978926 -0.53171029]
 [-0.69145056 -0.01186427  0.72232635]]
```

You can verify, that this is the correct eigensystem of `b`, however, the eigenvalues are not sorted and the eigenvectors are columns (so they span axis=-1). We want to fix both problems.

To start, we first find the ordering of the eigenvalues

```
ordering_e = e.argsort(axis=-1)
```

This ordering can be used in a very straightforward manner to order eigenvalues (here `e` is modified **in place**)

```
e[:] = np.take_along_axis(e, ordering_e, axis=-1)
```

For the vectors, we need to extend the shape of the ordering array. Specifically, the vectors for different eigenvalues are enumerated by the last index in `v`, but their components are stored in the second to last index, we need an extra dummy dimension in our `argsort` variable. Think of it as a shape expansion: (..., dim) -> (..., dim, dim). This can be achieved by using `np.newaxis` several times. The number of times is given by the dimensionality of the original matrices, which is also the last dimension of `e.shape`. Put together:

```
ordering_v = np.repeat(ordering_e[...,np.newaxis,:], e.shape[-1], axis=-2)
```

The eigenvectors can now be rearranged the same way (also in-place)

```
v[:] = np.take_along_axis(v, ordering_v, axis=-1)
```

Finally, the transposition can be done by numpy's `moveaxis`. Since we're transposing the last two levels, this will do the trick

```
v[:] = np.moveaxis(v, -2, -1)
```

Note, that `moveaxis(arr, m, n)` is generally different from `moveaxis(arr, n, m)`, but since we're transposing the last two levels, -2, -1 is identical to -1, -2.

And that's all, the two prints now give

```
[-2.12921985  0.43934625 10.6898736]
[[-0.44218639 -0.53171029  0.72232635]
[-0.77667543  0.62978926 -0.01186427]
[-0.44860502 -0.56625935 -0.69145056]]
```

I.e. exactly what we wanted: sorted eigenvalues and correspondingly sorted eigenvectors, with the components spanning the last level.

TL;DR: use this code that sorts the eigensystem **in-place**

```
def sort_eigensystem(E,V):
       ordering_E = E.argsort(axis=-1)
       E[:] = np.take_along_axis(E, ordering_E, axis=-1)
       ordering_V = np.repeat(ordering_E[...,np.newaxis,:], E.shape[-1], axis=-2)
       V[:] = np.moveaxis(np.take_along_axis(V, ordering_v, axis=-1), -2, -1)
```